# How to draw a PGF picture in front of any other PGF picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, layers

I saved the following LaTeX code in the file `~\Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw[fill,red](0,0)rectangle(\textwidth,\textheight);
       \draw[fill,orange](0,0)circle(2pt);
       \draw[fill,orange](\textwidth,\textheight)circle(2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The code creates a beamer presentation whose theme is Warsaw. (The Warsaw theme adds headers and footers to every frame.) The presentation consists of a single, regular frame. The frame's content consists of a single object: a TikZ picture. The picture is composed of three elements: a filled red rectangle whose width is `\textwidth` and whose height is `\textheight`, and two filled orange circles at the bottom left and top right corners of the red rectangle.

I then executed the following commands in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
> lualatex Test
```

At the end of the compilation `~/Test.log` did not contain any instructions to rerun the compilation. The compilation resulted in the creation of the file `~/Test.pdf`. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows.

[image: A beamer slide with a red rectangle]

As can be seen, the orange circle at the top right corner of the red rectangle is visible, but the one at the bottom left corner is invisible. This indicates that part of the red rectangle is hidden behind the black and blue footer.

---

**Questions**

1. How can the red rectangle be drawn in front of the footer?
2. More generally, how can a TikZ picture be drawn in front of any other TikZ picture that overlaps it, even without knowing which TikZ pictures, if any, actually overlap it, or even if there are any other TikZ pictures in the document?
3. Even more generally, how can a PGF picture be drawn in front of any other PGF picture? ([Apparently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668807/how-to-draw-a-tikz-picture-in-front-of-any-other-tikz-picture#comment1662754_668807) the footer of a `beamer` presentation of the `Warsaw` theme is not a TikZ picture, but a PGF picture. [Moreover](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668807/how-to-draw-a-tikz-picture-in-front-of-any-other-tikz-picture#comment1662769_668807), every TikZ picture is a PGF picture, but not vice versa.)

Comment: You could try the options `remember picture, overlay`.  The second option puts the picture out of the text-segment and on top of it.  Now, if you create the picture in the beamer context, it will not cover the footer, I think.

Comment: @DanielN This trick changes the position of the red rectangle on the page. I don't wish the position of the TikZ picture to change. I simply want it to become visible in full.

Comment: Your question is misleading. Do you want the tikzpicture in front of other tikzpictures or in front of other elements on the page? The footline is not a tikzpicture. The theme you choose uses a pgfpicture for the footline

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Is every `tikzpicture` a `pgfpicture`?

Comment: @DanielN What I think happens when you give the `overlay` option to a drawing command is that the command's drawing takes place in a layer that "sits" on top of all other layers. This layer is unique throughout a LaTeX document: if two commands in two  different `tikzpicture` environments are given the `overlay` option, they both draw on the same top-level layer. However, different `tikzpicture` environments set up different systems of coordinates on this top layer. Those systems of coordinates are local to each `tikzpicture` environments.

Comment: @DanielN  So, if you write `\draw[overlay](0,0)circle(1cm);` in two different `tikzpicture` environments, both circles will be drawn on the top layer, but possibly at different locations on the top layer: the first circle will be drawn about the point (0,0) w.r.t. the coordinate system set up locally by the first `tikzpicture` environment, whereas the second circle will be drawn about the point (0,0) w.r.t. the coordinate system set up locally by the second `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: @DanielN  And if the origins of these two systems of coordinates are mapped to two different points of the top level layer, then two distinct circles will get drawn.

Comment: @EvanAad Normally yes, but with latex there is always at least one user who does something unusual, so I wouldn't be surprised if someone redefined the tikzpicture.

Comment: The statement "adds headers and footers to every frame, except the title frame or other special frames" is also not true. Head and footline are added to all frames unless you switch them off, e.g. with the plain option. Beamer does not automatically disable them for the title page.

Comment: @DanielN (continuing my last comment) This is why, when the `overlay` option is added to the `tikzpicture` environment in the code listed in my question, the red rectangle changes position: the `overlay` option changes the environment's local coordinate system, or more accurately, it changes the mapping of the environment's local coordinate system to absolute positions on the physical page.

Comment: @DanielN The million dollar question is: why does the `overlay` option cause this change of mapping? I don't have an answer to this question.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've amended my question per your corrections. I hope now it's not misleading.

Comment: The title is still misleading. There aren't any other tikzpictures on your page, so your tikzpicture is automatically in front of all other tikzpictures.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I've corrected the title.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141385/discussion-between-evan-aad-and-samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to print some thing on top off everything you have to add it after the footer. You can e.g. use the shipout/foreground hook. When calculating the sizes, be aware that `\textheight` in beamer is much larger than you expect. It actually goes down to the bottom of the frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{%
  \put(1cm,-\paperheight){%
       \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw[fill,red,use as bounding box](0,0)rectangle(\textwidth,\paperheight);
       \draw[fill,orange](0,0)circle(2pt);
       \draw[fill,orange](\textwidth,\paperheight)circle(2pt);
       \draw[<->,green,line width=3pt](-2pt,0)--++(0,\textheight);
       \end{tikzpicture}}
       }
\begin{frame}[t]{Frame Title}
\mbox{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Why does the green arrow protrude into the header? In my example the red rectangle doesn't overlap the header.

Comment: as I wrote: \textheight is much larger then you expect. The green arrow starts at the bottom of the frame.

Comment: In my example, where is the (hidden) bottom of the red rectangle? Along the bottom of the page?

Comment: add `\pdfpageheight=20cm` after \begin{document}. This will enlarge the mediabox and you can see the bottom.

Comment: I see. Then in my example the hidden bottom of the red rectangle is below the bottom of the footer, whereas in your example the bottom of the red rectangle is along the bottom of the footer. Then it's not the same red rectangle. Your code did more than merely send the red rectangle to the front; it changed the dimensions of the red rectangle.

Comment: Or changed its position. Or both.

Comment: I put the zero point of the picture at the bottom left (+1cm in x direction): `\put(1cm,-\paperheight)`. The zero point of the hook is at the top left.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to suggest a variation on [Ulrike Fischer's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668823/21685). The variation avoids the `\put` command, and instead positions the elements of the TikZ picture relative to the `current page` pseudo-node.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,math}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
      \tikzmath{
         coordinate \origin;
         \origin = (current page.south west) + (1,0);
      }
      \draw[fill,red](\origin)rectangle++(\textwidth,\paperheight);
      \draw[fill,orange](\origin)circle(2pt);
      \draw[fill,orange]($(\origin)+(\textwidth,\paperheight)$)circle(2pt);
      \draw[<->,green,line width=3pt]($(\origin)+(-2pt,0)$)--++(0,\textheight);
   \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The output in both cases is the same:

[image: The output]

Answer (score 2):

If you look at Figure 1 of the beamer user guide, you'll see that the footline is drawn as the very top layer of a beamer frame. If you don't want it from covering your frame content, you can use a layer further down to show the footline.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\vskip3.625ex}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}
  {%
  \tiny%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \rule{0pt}{\dimexpr\paperheight-1.125ex}%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\nobreak\hfill\usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}\usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}}%
  \vskip0pt%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw[fill,red](0,0)rectangle(\textwidth,\textheight);
       \draw[fill,orange](0,0)circle(2pt);
       \draw[fill,orange](\textwidth,\textheight)circle(2pt);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For future reference: the figure appearing in the beginning of your answer is taken from section 8.2 *Components of a Frame* on p. 62 of *The BEAMER class User Guide* for version 3.68 (the current version).

Comment: 1. Does `beamer` provide hooks for executing code at the start or end of one of the `beamer` layers illustrated above? Or a way of appending code to the beginning and end of each of these layers? 2. The same question, but w.r.t. templates, such as the headline template. 3. Is it possible to create a new template e.g. for the headline, that calls the theme's template for this element without knowing its internals, much like it is possible to call a LaTeX macro by name without knowing the details of its implementation?

Comment: @EvanAad 1. + 2.  Have a look at `\addtobeamertemplate{...}{}{}`

Comment: 3. `\usebeamertemplate{...}`, but you don't want to blindly  insert templates into other ones. You need to adapt them to the situation (fontsize/positioning/current mode)

Comment: A template's content is drawn/typeset inside a bounding box, right? Is there a way to tell the size and position on the page of this box? For instance, suppose I'd like to know the size and position on the page of the headline box. Can I query these pieces of information inside the third pair-of-braces of `addtobeamertemplate{headline}{}{}`?

Comment: Place a tikzmark at the bottom of the headline and you'll know its position. No need to know the actual height. Or use the `\headheight`