# Is there an overview of Beamer's slide (page) geometry anywhere?

Tags: beamer, margins

I find this classic figure of LaTeX's page geometry very helpful:

[image: geometry]

Source: http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Latex_layout.svg

Now, I am fiddling with some `beamer` slides and I could really use such an overview of `beamer`'s slide layout. Does it exist anywhere? I have not been able to find it...

For now, I need it to figure out how to get the height of a frame's body.

Comment: I don't think that a similar picture will ever exist; the geometry depends on how the used theme has been made, whether if the title bar count or not in the `\textheight`. You could read the manual (section 8.2.2 the sidebars): you will find some dimensions here

Comment: It's not quite what you want, but you might find http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26299/86 a little bit helpful.

Comment: @LionelMANSUY: To which manual are you refering? Is it the one of geometry?

Comment: @strpeter I was talking about the Beamer's manual

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the code provided by the author of the image. I tried with this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{layout}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\layout
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and got a single page with the beamer's slide layout.

Package layout, as far as I remember, creates the layout diagram for the current geometry of the document. In the previous code, for example, if you change the document class to article and remove the environment frame, you will obtain a layout like the one you put. For more information, check the package documentation.

I hope it is still useful.

[image]

Comment: At another place [1] on stackexchange it is mentioned that the \textheight includes the header. That would mean that the above graphic is wrong ... 

  [1]: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/384615/is-textheight-in-beamer-slides-with-a-title-wrong