# Latex Beamer: Prevent vertical text overflow for multi column or minipages

Tags: beamer, columns, height

To get a feeling for the sizes of the area reserved for text in different latex beamer layouts (themes) I am filling the text area with \blindtext. This works for simple frames with single column content. But when using multi column environments vertical text overflow appears. This happens for both, the columns and the minipage environments.

In addition to the question stated in the title, it would be great if someone knows a way to visualize the maximum space reserved for different contents like titles, text, headers, footers, etc. for different themes.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}
%#############################################################
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\blindtext
\end{frame}

% Two columns using minipage
\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\blindtext
\end{minipage}  
\end{frame}

% Two columns using columns
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\blindtext
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
\blindtext
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The three output frames from the above MWE are shown below:

1. frame: simple frame output as expected
2. frame: Two columns using minipage environment, vertical text overflow
3. frame: Two columns using columns environment, vertical text overflow
   [image]

Comment: Have you tried loading the `showframe` package?

Comment: For your secondary question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167711/showing-margins-frames-in-beamer-slides and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96201/is-there-an-overview-of-beamers-slide-page-geometry-anywhere

Comment: Currently the whole available text space is filled (and some more off the page, but this is not visible). How far would you like the available space to be filled? 80%? 90%? [If you would take a longer text, you'll get the same effect on the one column frame]

Comment: @samcarter I thought one purpose of a theme was to limit the maximum space occupied by the text. So the default setting in this theme would limit the text width but use the vertical space until the very bottom?

Comment: @StackJack The classical available beamer themes normally do nothing to change the available space, they rather define how all the elements look like. It is in the responsibility of the user that the content will fit onto the frame. The vertical space is not limited by the bottom, if you put more on the slide, it will be typeset below the bottom and thus be invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the space which is occupied in your example is the available space. It is in the responsibility of the user that the content will fit onto the frame, if too much text is put on a frame, it will simply overflow at the bottom (with the exception of frames using `allowframebreak`, but this should only be used as emergency solution, for example for the bibliography).

If you would use a longer text in your one column example (e.g. `\blindtext \blindtext`), you would see the same effect.

If you want a blindtext with more flexible lenght for demonstration purpose of your theme, I suggest the `lipsum` package instead, as this allows to select which paragraph of the sample text should be used:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Frankfurt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%#############################################################
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\lipsum[21]
\end{frame}

% Two columns using minipage
\begin{frame}
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\lipsum[11]
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
\lipsum[11]
\end{minipage}  
\end{frame}

% Two columns using columns
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\lipsum[11]
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
\lipsum[11]
\end{column}

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough in my question. I was not looking for another way to create shorter or better matching filling text. I was just surprised that the default settings of the beamer class do not leave any space at the bottom of the page/slide like (all?) other 'standard' latex document classes (article, report, book, etc.) with their default settings. And as you pointed out correctly this has nothing to do with the amount of columns. So please include your comment "The vertical space is not limited by the bottom, ..." in your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @StackJack I added a few more sentences - I hope it now better fits your question. The comparison to standard latex documents is a bit problematic, as in a standard document the text can simply be continued on the next page, while presentation slides should consist of individually composed slides.