# Add content behind beamer background (or theme)

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

I have a custom beamer template that frames the content of each slide, like the standard themes but with wiggly header/footer lines.

I add the background image of the template with

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}
 {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{master.png}}
```

I now want the content to be behind the background image and the rest of the template (title, page number...). The template will then have a cut-out with the content visible underneath. The background image can have .png or .pdf transparency.

Kind of like:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passe-Partout_%28framing%29

Does anyone have an idea how to move the content behind the background image?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How about including the image with `textpos` in the footline? According to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26299/how-does-beamer-build-the-frame this should be the component drawn as the top layer

Comment: nice idea. I tried but unfortunately this overwrites the title. Including it before the title let's it remain under the content. So I guess my question includes: how do I make the title come into foreground?

Comment: mmm, that is too bad. Could you share an example of your code? It would be easier to modify an existing code in order to find an solution instead of having to write own stuff ...

Comment: How about leaving the traditional title layer empty and including the title in the footline layer [after the passpartout]?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

In order to have the title in front of the picture: How about leaving the traditional frametitle layer empty and including the frametitle in the footline layer?

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=blue!20}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\fontsize{24}{28},series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth]{mybackground}{back.pdf}

\providecommand\insertframetitle{} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(0,0){%
            \pgfuseimage{mybackground}
        }
        \put(25,220){%
            \begin{minipage}[b][0mm][t]{100mm}
                \usebeamerfont{frametitle}{
                    \usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}{
                        \insertframetitle
                    }
                }
            \end{minipage}
        }
    \end{picture}
}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace*{2.5cm}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Test Test Test}
        test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test  test
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try overlaying the image using `textpos` or `tikz`, instead of setting it as the background.

See:
[How can I position an image in an arbitrary position in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/how-can-i-position-an-image-in-an-arbitrary-position-in-beamer)