# How may I keep my logo at the front of my slide

Tags: beamer

May be the title is confusing. Let me explain what I want:

I am using beamer to create my slide and on the first page, in order to match my school style, I fill up the entire first slide with red color. Now I want to add the school logo in the first slide. I am using code

```
\titlegraphic{
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(0\textwidth,8.5cm)
\includegraphics[height=.8cm,width=14cm]{logo-polito-heng} 
\end{textblock*}}
```

this code works good at the rest of my slide, of course, without `\titlegraphic` part. However, at the front page, my logo is totally missing... I guess it is covered by red color which I am using to fill up my first page...

Now the question is, how may I keep my logo at the front of my slide? Any comments would be very thankful!!!!

Comment: And how exactly are you filling your first page with the red color? Please provide a complete, minimal document showing the relevant settings.

Comment: Depending on the `beamer` theme with respect to its position there is a `\logo{...}` command in `beamer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you fill the `background` (or the `background canvas`) with red, everything else will appear over it.

I'd suggest reading [Andrew Stacey answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27302/1952) to [How does beamer build the frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26299/how-does-beamer-build-the-frame) for better understanding how `beamer` builds frames.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=2cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}
\title{Red background frame with logo}
\author{TeX.SX}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\color{red}\rule{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: One more question. How may I change the text color in the first page? For example, how may I change "Red Background frame with logo" to white color? as well as the rest? Thax!!

Comment: @user124358: `Beamer` uses `themes` to fix all components appearance. I think it's better to use themes to change colors, fonts, etc. but if you prefer fixing them by hand include `\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=white}\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=white}\setbeamercolor{date}{fg=white,bg=blue}` and see what happen. After that I'd suggest taking a walk through [`beamer` questions and answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beamer)  here and taking a look to [beamer documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/beamer)