# beamer: make a picture stay in the foreground

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, beamerposter

I am trying to write some style file for a poster framework, we can use. The header is almost ready:

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=15cm]{headline}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    %title text
      \node [anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt,text width=60cm] at ($(current page.north west)+(4.5cm,-2.8cm)$)
    {
    {\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor{headline}\color{fg}\inserttitle\par}%
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
    \else%
        \vskip28mm\par%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor{headline}\color{fg}\insertsubtitle\par}%
    \fi%
    %{\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor{headline}\color{fg}\insertauthor\par}%
    %   {\usebeamerfont{institute}\usebeamercolor{headline}\color{fg}\insertinstitute\par}              
    };
    %hzdr logo
    \node [anchor=north east,inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north east)-(2cm,2.8cm)$)
    {\includegraphics[width=22.39cm,hiresbb]{HIF_E_weiss_auf_transparent}};
    %
    \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt] at ($(current page.north east)-(-3cm,13cm)$)
    {\includegraphics[hiresbb]{PIKTO_ENGL_300DPI21}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{beamercolorbox}
}
```

The last picture is out of the actual header. And it should be visible, i.e. should stay in the forerground, not matter what to add under the header of the poster. Mainly the poster is made of other beamercolorboxes:

```
\newcommand\posterblock[4][]
{
\fcolorbox{hzdr-blue}{white}{
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep*=1ex,#1]{bgblock}%use bigger values for colsep* if you want to make the box around the text bigger;warning: if you use the option rounded this will disable the horizontal spaces around the text
        \begin{block}{\usebeamerfont{block title}#2}\justify
            {\usebeamerfont{small block title}\color{hzdr-blue}{#3}}\vspace{2ex}

            {\usebeamerfont{block body}#4}
        \end{block}
    \end{beamercolorbox}}
    \quad
}
```

But when I am using this posterblock, it will always over the picture. Can anybody help and make the picture stay in the foreground?

Comment: In http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27302/36296 the different layers of an frame are displayed. You could arrange your picture an layer which lays above your header

Answer (score 3):

Beamer places the different frame components in layers on top of each other:

[image]
[Image borrowed from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27302/36296, see there for further information]

If you want the image to be on top, choose an appropriate layer, for example the footline.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
        \put(0,95){\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
    \end{picture}   
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
        Bla
  \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

[image]