# What is difference between template's `background` and `background canvas`?

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

What is difference between:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\shade[top color=yellow!75!green!33,bottom color=blue!66!green!33,middle color=blue!6!green!33]
  ([shift={(0.0cm,0.0cm)}]current page.north west)
     rectangle
  ([shift={(0.0cm,0.0cm)}]current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}  
}
```

and:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\shade[top color=yellow!75!green!33,bottom color=blue!66!green!33,middle color=blue!6!green!33]
  ([shift={(0.0cm,0.0cm)}]current page.north west)
     rectangle
  ([shift={(0.0cm,0.0cm)}]current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}  
}
```

First one behaves corectly, the second one behaves randomly on each rebuild? I build it with `pdflatex` and with `gummi` (preview). And the second one doesn't show any background when I don't rebuild, but build from scratch. Quite weird for me.

Edit: even first one behaves randomly with different themes...

Comment: Take a look at [How does beamer build the frame?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27302/1952)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `beamer` user guide:

[image]

So, the `background canvas` goes behind everything, and on that comes `background` and then main contents.

Compare these codes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {here};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\shade[top color=yellow!75!green!33,bottom color=blue!66!green!33,middle color=blue!6!green!33]
  ([shift={(0.0cm,0.0cm)}]current page.north west)
     rectangle
  ([shift={(0.0cm,0.0cm)}]current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    Some
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node at (current page.center) {here};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\shade[top color=yellow!75!green!33,bottom color=blue!66!green!33,middle color=blue!6!green!33]
  ([shift={(0.0cm,0.0cm)}]current page.north west)
     rectangle
  ([shift={(0.0cm,0.0cm)}]current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    Some
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In first you see `here` at the center and in second it goes behind (as it is inside `background canvas`.

Comment: And when you use `remember picture`, you have to compile 2-3 times to settle down.

Comment: Thanks. You answered the question, as it seems, bug is caused by something else.