# beamer: Difference between \setbeamertemplate{background canvas} and \usebackgroundtemplate (and \setbeamertemplate{background})

Tags: beamer

### Question

When I want to change the background of a `beamer` presentation I used to use something like this:

```
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}%
{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]%
    {%
        Picture.jpg
    }%
}
```

which is also documented in the `beamer` documentation. In some answers here I often see

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Picture.jpg}
}
```

1. Is there a best practice?
2. Surprisingly I can't find `\usebackgroundtemplate` when searching in the `beamer` documentation.

### Related

- [What is difference between template's `background` and `background canvas`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215336/) (I added `\setbeamertemplate{background}` so that the question title is more complete)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Concerning your questions what `\usebackgroundtemplate` does:

  It's defined in `beamerbasecompatibility.sty` as

  ```
  \def\usebackgroundtemplate{\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}}
  ```

  From the filename I would conclude, that commands defined for compatibility are not the ones to be used as "best practice" - but the result should be the same.
- For the difference of `\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}` and `\setbeamertemplate{background}`:

  Basically these are two different layers, see [How does beamer build the frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26299/how-does-beamer-build-the-frame/27302#27302) for an overview.