# How to add vertical lines at the extreme left and right of a poster using beamer

Tags: beamer, beamerposter, posters

How can I add vertical lines at the extreme left and right of a poster (using beamer) so that it is wholly surrounded by a box ?

For the moment, my poster looks like that

http://www.docdroid.net/wdte/test.pdf.html

that is, I have two horizontal lines at the top and at the bottom and I want to add two vertical ones to close the box. I am using the beamer theme named I6pd2.

Shown are my minimal .tex document

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
%\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usetheme{I6pd2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
%\usepackage{times}\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  % obsolete
\usefonttheme{serif}
\graphicspath{ {./img/} }
%\boldmath
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}
% change list indention level
% \setdefaultleftmargin{3em}{}{}{}{}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\providecommand\thispdfpagelabel[1]{}
%\usepackage{snapshot} % will write a .dep file with all dependencies, allows for easy bundling
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered tabularx columns
\newcommand{\pphantom}{\textcolor{ta3aluminium}} % phantom introduces a vertical space in p formatted table columns??!!
\newcommand{\psihat}{\hat{\psi}}
\newcommand{\phihat}{\hat{\phi}}
\newcommand{\rt}{(\mathbf{r},t)}
\newcommand{\xt}{(x,t)}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{|#1\rangle}\xspace}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle #1|}\xspace}
\newcommand{\elemm}[3]{\ensuremath{\bra{#1}#2\ket{#3}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\ensuremath{\langle #1|#2\rangle}\xspace}
\newcommand\psfragg[2]{\psfrag{#1}{\small #2}}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{100,0,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{75,25,100}

\listfiles
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\newcommand{\myref}[5]{\textcolor{darkgreen}{{\footnotesize [#1 \textit{et al.} #2 \textbf{#3}, #4 (#5)]}}}
\newcommand{\myrefarxiv}[1]{\textcolor{darkgreen}{{\footnotesize [arXiv #1]}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{A}
\author{B}
\institute[C]{D}
\date{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength{\columnheight}
\setlength{\columnheight}{105cm}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% Set up a column 
\begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
\begin{minipage}[T]{.98\textwidth}
\parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% fill each column with content            
\begin{block}{}

\end{block}

\begin{block}{}            

\end{block}

\begin{block}{}      

\end{block}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{mdframed}[style=innerleftmargin=20pt,innerrightmargin=20pt, innertopmargin=0pt, skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt, linewidth=2pt]%
\usebeamerfont{block body}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1em,colsep*=.0ex,sep=0.5ex,vmode]{block body}%

\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{mdframed}%
}

\end{minipage}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{column}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% end the column
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% Set up a column 
\begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
\begin{minipage}[T]{.98\textwidth} 
\parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{ 
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% fill each column with content

\begin{block}{}

\end{block}

\begin{block}{}

\end{block}
\vfill
}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% end the column
\end{minipage}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{column}
% ---------------------------------------------------------% 

% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% Set up a column 
\begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
\begin{minipage}[T]{.98\textwidth} 
\parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{ 
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
 % fill each column with content

\begin{block}{}

\end{block}

\begin{block}{}

\end{block}
}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
 % end the column
\end{minipage}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{column}
% ---------------------------------------------------------% 
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
%%% End:
```

and the corresponding theme

```
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthemeI6pd2}  % this style was created by Thomas Deselaers an Philippe Dreuw

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{tangocolors}
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
%\mode<presentation>

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setbeamercolor{headline}{fg=black,bg=myblue1} % Cadre du dessus et du dessous
\setbeamercolor{footline}{fg=tabutter, bg=ta3gray}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\large,series=\tt}
\setbeamercolor{separation line}{bg=myblue3} % Ligne de séparation entre poster et cadre du dessus et du dessous
\setbeamercolor{title in headline}{fg=myblue3} % Couleur titre
\setbeamercolor{author in headline}{fg=black} % Couleur auteurs
\setbeamercolor{institute in headline}{fg=black} % Couleur instistut

\setbeamercolor{framesubtitle}{fg=ta3orange, bg=ta2gray} 
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=ta2orange, bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=ta2orange, bg=black}

\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=tachameleon, bg=myblue1} % Couleur du fond du poster
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=white,fg=black} % Couleur du texte et du fond des cadres
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{fg=black,bg=myblue2} % Couleur titre cadre
\setbeamerfont{block title}{size=\large,series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{upper separation line head}{fg=ta2orange}

\setbeamercolor*{example body}{fg=ta3aluminium,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=ta3aluminium,bg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{example title}{bg=taorange,fg=ta2gray}

%\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=ta3gray}

%\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=taorange}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=myblue3} % Couleur des items

\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}  % no navigation on a poster

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\mdfdefinestyle{topbox}{bottomline=false,innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt, innertopmargin=0pt, skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt, linewidth=2pt}
\mdfdefinestyle{bottombox}{topline=false,innerleftmargin=20pt,innerrightmargin=20pt, innertopmargin=0pt, skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt, linewidth=2pt}
\setbeamertemplate{block begin}{
  \vskip.75ex
\begin{mdframed}[style=topbox]%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0pt, ht=4ex,dp=0.5ex,center,colsep*=0ex]{block title}%
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}%
    \vbox to 3ex{{\vfil\insertblocktitle\vfil}}% phantom because of baseline problem
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
\end{mdframed}%
\begin{mdframed}[style=bottombox]%
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1em,colsep*=.0ex,sep=0.5ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{} \justifying %
}

  \setbeamertemplate{block end}{
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{mdframed}%
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\mdfdefinestyle{topbox}{bottomline=false,innerleftmargin=0pt,innerrightmargin=0pt, innertopmargin=0pt, skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt, linewidth=2pt}
\mdfdefinestyle{bottombox}{topline=false,innerleftmargin=20pt,innerrightmargin=20pt, innertopmargin=0pt, skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt, linewidth=2pt}
\setbeamertemplate{exampleblock begin}{
  \vskip.75ex
\begin{mdframed}[style=topbox]%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0pt, ht=4ex,dp=0.5ex,center,colsep*=0ex]{block title}%
    \usebeamerfont*{block title}%
    \vbox to 3ex{{\vfil\insertblocktitle\vfil}}% phantom because of baseline problem
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
\end{mdframed}%
\begin{mdframed}[style=bottombox]%
  {\ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{}{\nointerlineskip\vskip-0.5pt}}%
  \usebeamerfont{block body}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1em,colsep*=.0ex,sep=0.5ex,vmode]{block body}%
    \ifbeamercolorempty[bg]{block body}{\vskip-.25ex}{\vskip-.75ex}\vbox{} \justifying %
}

  \setbeamertemplate{exampleblock end}{
  \end{beamercolorbox}
\end{mdframed}%
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
  \leavevmode
 \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line head}
    \rule{0pt}{3pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{headline}
    \begin{columns}[T]
      \begin{column}{.02\paperwidth}
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.80\paperwidth}
        \centering
        \vskip10ex
        \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\color{fg}\textbf{\LARGE{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}
        \vskip7.5ex
        \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\color{fg}\Large{\insertauthor}\\[2ex]}
        \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}     
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.15\paperwidth}
        \vskip8ex
        \begin{center}

        \end{center}
        \vskip2ex
      \end{column}
      \begin{column}{.02\paperwidth}
      \end{column}
    \end{columns}
    \vskip2ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line head}
    \rule{0pt}{3pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

%  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{  
%    \leavevmode
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=0.5cm,wd=.8\paperwidth]{headline}
%      \usebeamercolor{title in headline}{\raggedleft\color{fg}\textbf{\LARGE{\inserttitle}}\\[1ex]}
%      \usebeamercolor{author in headline}{\raggedleft\color{fg}\large{\insertauthor}\\[1ex]}
%      \usebeamercolor{institute in headline}{\raggedleft\color{fg}\large{\insertinstitute}\\[1ex]}     
%    \end{beamercolorbox}%
%    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth]{logo in headline}
%      \centering
%      \LARGE{LOGO}
%    \end{beamercolorbox}  


%}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line foot}
    \rule{0pt}{3pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4ex,leftskip=1em,rightskip=1em]{headline}%
    \textcolor{black}{\texttt{xxx}}
    \hfill
    \textcolor{black}{\texttt{yyy}}
    \vskip1ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line foot}
    \rule{0pt}{3pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Display a grid to help align images ... and it looks nice with this color scheme
%\beamertemplategridbackground[1cm]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\mode<all>

% adapt height of imtemize rectangles
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\raisebox{0.12ex}{$\bullet$}\hskip0.1em}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\raisebox{0.12ex}{$\circ$}\hskip0.1em}
% or define your own template using \defbeamertemplate{itemize item}, see beameruserguide.pdf

% equal font sizes for all levels
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate body}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\normalsize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=\normalsize}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
%%% TeX-master: "poster-surf"
%%% End:
```

Comment: You could put an \fbox around a minipage containing the slide contents.

Comment: This solution does not match with what I am expecting. Putting a minibox surrounded by a \fbox indeed creates 2 vertical lines, but they do not include neither the block title nor the footer. Furthermore, those lines are not at the extreme left and right of the poster.

Any other solution ?

Comment: Is all of this really necessary, or is this just the code you were using at the time?  In particular, how does one obtain beamerthemeI6pd2?

Answer (score 1):

You are already using `TiKZ`, then you can use

```
\tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[red, line width=1cm]% 
     ([shift={(1cm,-1cm)}]current page.north west) rectangle%
     ([shift={(-1cm,1cm)}]current page.south east);}
```

to draw a rectangle around the poster. Of course you need to adjust `line width`, color and corners (`shift`) according your taste.

My first idea was just include previous command inside poster `frame`, but  [How does beamer build the frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26299/how-does-beamer-build-the-frame) shows that  `footline` is the last layer to be drawn and this is done inside `\end{frame}`.
Therefore, anything you draw inside a `\frame` can be overdrawn by `footline` contents.

A solution for this problem could be to include previous `TiKZ` command inside `footline` template definition as following code shows. (Note: I've simplified the example and used original I6pd2 theme)

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usetheme{I6pd2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{tikz}
\providecommand\thispdfpagelabel[1]{}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{100,0,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{75,25,100}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{My poster}
\author{Me}
\institute[My institute]{A longer name for my institute}
\date{}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{upper separation line foot}
    \rule{0pt}{2pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}

  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=4ex,leftskip=1cm,rightskip=1cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \texttt{http://www.texstackexchange.com}
    \hfill
    \texttt{xxxxxxxxxxxxx}
    \vskip1ex
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{lower separation line foot}
    \rule{0pt}{2pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[red, thick] ([shift={(1cm,-1cm)}]current page.north west)rectangle([shift={(-1cm,1cm)}]current page.south east);}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

**Update** (20/04/2015)

Instead of repeating `\setbeamertemplate` in your main file or changing it in theme file, another option could be `\addtobeamertemplate` which works in this case.

Now the code is your code with border line inclusion and the result shows what I get with your theme file copied from [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/2577400pksvpc#/6773785/)

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
%\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed}
\usepackage{showexpl}
\usetheme{I6pd2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
%\usepackage{times}\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}  % obsolete
\usefonttheme{serif}
\graphicspath{ {./img/} }
%\boldmath
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}
% change list indention level
% \setdefaultleftmargin{3em}{}{}{}{}{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\providecommand\thispdfpagelabel[1]{}
%\usepackage{snapshot} % will write a .dep file with all dependencies, allows for easy bundling
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered tabularx columns
\newcommand{\pphantom}{\textcolor{ta3aluminium}} % phantom introduces a vertical space in p formatted table columns??!!
\newcommand{\psihat}{\hat{\psi}}
\newcommand{\phihat}{\hat{\phi}}
\newcommand{\rt}{(\mathbf{r},t)}
\newcommand{\xt}{(x,t)}
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{|#1\rangle}\xspace}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle #1|}\xspace}
\newcommand{\elemm}[3]{\ensuremath{\bra{#1}#2\ket{#3}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\braket}[2]{\ensuremath{\langle #1|#2\rangle}\xspace}
\newcommand\psfragg[2]{\psfrag{#1}{\small #2}}
\newcommand\psfraggg[2]{\psfrag{#1}{\footnotesize #2}}
\newcommand\psfragggg[2]{\psfrag{#1}{\scriptsize #2}}
\newcommand\psfraggggg[2]{\psfrag{#1}{\tiny #2}}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\definecolor{darkred}{RGB}{100,0,0}
\definecolor{darkblue}{RGB}{75,25,100}

\listfiles
\definecolor{darkgreen}{RGB}{0,100,0}
\newcommand{\myref}[5]{\textcolor{darkgreen}{{\footnotesize [#1 \textit{et al.} #2 \textbf{#3}, #4 (#5)]}}}
\newcommand{\myrefarxiv}[1]{\textcolor{darkgreen}{{\footnotesize [arXiv #1]}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\title{My title}
\author{My name and coauthors}
\institute[A shorter name for my institute]{My institute}
\date{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newlength{\columnheight}
\setlength{\columnheight}{105cm}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% This is the modified template. It needs two runs.    
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{}{
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{\draw[red, thick] ([shift={(1cm,-1cm)}]current page.north west)rectangle([shift={(-1cm,1cm)}]current page.south east);}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% Set up a column 
\begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
\begin{minipage}[T]{.98\textwidth}
\parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% fill each column with content            
\begin{block}{}

\end{block}

\begin{block}{}            

\end{block}

\begin{block}{}      

\end{block}

\begin{block}{}

\end{block}
}

\end{minipage}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{column}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% end the column
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% Set up a column 
\begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
\begin{minipage}[T]{.98\textwidth} 
\parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{ 
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% fill each column with content

\begin{block}{}

\end{block}

\begin{block}{}

\end{block}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\begin{mdframed}[style=innerleftmargin=20pt,innerrightmargin=20pt, innertopmargin=0pt, skipabove=0pt,skipbelow=0pt, linewidth=2pt]%
\usebeamerfont{block body}%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[leftskip=1em,colsep*=.0ex,sep=0.5ex,vmode]{block body}%

\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{mdframed}%
\vfill
}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% end the column
\end{minipage}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{column}
% ---------------------------------------------------------% 

% ---------------------------------------------------------%
% Set up a column 
\begin{column}{.33\textwidth}
\begin{beamercolorbox}[center,wd=\textwidth]{postercolumn}
\begin{minipage}[T]{.98\textwidth} 
\parbox[t][\columnheight]{\textwidth}{ 
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
 % fill each column with content

\begin{block}{}

\end{block}

\begin{block}{}

\end{block}

\begin{block}{}

\end{block}
}
% ---------------------------------------------------------%
 % end the column
\end{minipage}
\end{beamercolorbox}
\end{column}
% ---------------------------------------------------------% 
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-PDF-mode: t
%%% End:
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've added your code in the poster template and it works ! At least, it works the first time I compile the .tex because when I recompile it without changing anything in the source, the red box you draw is shifted vertically. Any idea why ? Do you encounter the same issue ?

Comment: @Renaud In my system (MiKTeX 2.9) and with my example, the red box doesn't move on second or further compilations.

Comment: @Renaud   I don't know what could be wrong so I've copied an example with *.sty files in [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/2540381xhqbzm). Try to see what happens ther and let me know.

Comment: I've just read by chance that the overlay option requires 2 compilations in order to place the drawn figure at the proper location. In my case, it's just the contrary. I'm running out of time now, but I'm going to try your example tomorrow morning and then let you know if something goes wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been very busy these last days. I don't understand what's happening. I've also copied a minimal example file of my poster in Overleaf ( https://www.overleaf.com/2577400pksvpc#/6773781 ) with the suitable *.sty files and it does produce the expected result ! However, when I compile it on my own, It doesn't (see http://www.petit-fichier.fr/2015/04/20/test/test.pdf )

Comment: @Renaud I've updated the answer with a shorter solution. For your problem with different results, I'd suggest to delete all auxiliary files in your working folder and start again with compilation. Or even start again in a new empty folder. Also test what version packages do you use in your system compared with overlef. `\listfiles` (that you already included) shows all information in .log file.

Comment: Still, I don't understand what's wrong. I've downloaded a zipped file from Overleaf ( https://www.overleaf.com/2577400pksvpc#/6773781/ ) - where I've put the box in green instead of red to prevent collision with older versions - and compiled the .tex file within the unzipped resulting folder, and it still procudes the same result, that is a vertically shifted box. I've also tested it on another computer (which uses windows instead of linux, which I'm currently using) and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: @Renaud: Do you compile it twice? When using `overlays` and `remember pictures`, two compilations are nedded before getting the correct result. is this the problem?

Comment: Yes of course, I've compiled it many times. What's weird is that the result looks good after the first compilation. The shifted box (as I showed previously) only appears after the second - and after all future - compilations.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is that my version of latex is old ?  latex --version pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.0

Comment: @Renaud If same code works in overleaf, probably is a problem with an outdated package. I'd suggest to update. Most recent version is TeX Live 2014 and 2015 is under production.