# How to create Beamer template?

Tags: beamer

If there is any way to create this kind of beamer template?

Here is Title page
[image: title frame]

Here is the subframe
[image: sub frame]

Here is the logo they use

[image]

Comment: Yes. There is a way to create it.

Comment: I suggest that you read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146529/design-a-custom-beamer-theme-from-scratch and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26299/how-does-beamer-build-the-frame.  Then attempt to build your new Beamer style (aka template).  If you have specific questions as you build, provide a MWE and there are lots of friendly folks here who will help.

Comment: @cfr,could you give me some hints?

Comment: @R.Schumacher, many thanks, what is MWE?

Comment: @HowChen Start here for nice discussion of MWE (minimum working example).

Comment: @R.Schumacher doesn't want to make life too easy for you, it seems ;). I think that 'here' is [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Try to ask more specific questions as you hit obstacles. Right now, an answer would involve developing a new theme for Beamer, more-or-less. That is not a reasonable expectation.  Note that I'm really not even clear what the images you've posted are supposed to be. Is that 3 frames? 2? 1? Presumably not 1 because it is the wrong shape. The bottom bit looks like a logo - presumably you have a separate image file for that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As **cfr** mentioned in [`her comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275114/how-to-create-beamer-template/275123#comment661920_275114), the answer is yes. However, designing a complete `beamer` theme requires (re)defining many elements and might require a considerable amount of work. Below you'll find a starting point in which I redefined the `title page`, the `footline`, the `itemize item`, `itemize subitem` and `itemize subsubitem` templates:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{mypres}{RGB}{240,126,1}

% setting some colors for the theme
\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=mypres,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=mypres,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=mypres,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{date in head/foot}{fg=gray,bg=white}

% definition of the footline template
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mytheme}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{title in head/foot}%
    \makebox[2em][l]{{\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\textcolor{mypres}{\insertframenumber}}}%
    {\usebeamercolor{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.3\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm,right]{title in head/foot}%
    \includegraphics[width=.2\paperwidth,height=2.5ex,keepaspectratio]{gemalto}\hspace*{2em}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

% definition of the title page template
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mytheme}[1][]
{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \filldraw[mypres]
    (current page.north west) --
    ([yshift=-2cm]current page.north west) --
    ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=-2cm]current page.north east) {[rounded corners=15pt]--
    ([xshift=-2cm,yshift=3cm]current page.south east)} --
    ([yshift=3cm]current page.south west) --
    (current page.south west) --
    (current page.south east) --
    (current page.north east) -- cycle
    ;
  \node[text=mypres,anchor=south west,font=\sffamily\LARGE,text width=.55\paperwidth] 
  at ([xshift=10pt,yshift=-1cm]current page.west)
  (title)
  {\raggedright\inserttitle};   
  \node[anchor=west]
  at (title.east)
  {\includegraphics[height=0.75cm]{gemalto}};
  \node[text=white,font=\large\sffamily,anchor=south west]
  at ([xshift=30pt,yshift=0.5cm]current page.south west)
  (date)
  {\insertdate};
  \node[text=white,font=\large\sffamily,anchor=south west]
  at ([yshift=5pt]date.north west)
  (author)
  {\insertauthor};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% remove navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% definition of the symbols used in itemize
\newcommand\mysymbol{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=0.85]
  \fill[mypres]
  (-1ex,1ex) to[out=-60,in=240,looseness=1.2]
  (1ex,1ex) to[out=240,in=120,looseness=1.2]
  (1ex,-1ex) to[out=120,in=60,looseness=1.2]
  (-1ex,-1ex) to[out=60,in=-60,looseness=1.2]
  cycle;  
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }

% definition of the itemize templates
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{mysymbol}{\small\raise0.5pt\hbox{\mysymbol}}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subitem}{mysymbol}{\footnotesize\raise0.5pt\hbox{\mysymbol}}
\defbeamertemplate*{itemize subsubitem}{mysymbol}{\footnotesize\raise0.5pt\hbox{\mysymbol}}

\title[The short title]{The title of the presentation}
\author{The Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{A test frame title}
\framesubtitle{A test frame subtitle}
\begin{itemize}
  \item This is some item.
  \item Another item.
  \begin{itemize}
    \item A subitem.
    \item Another subitem.
  \end{itemize}
  \item Yet another item.
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oops, the logo in the lower right corner of the second slide is skewed.  I think you might be missing `keepaspectratio` in the arguments to `\includegraphics`.  Either way +1, great work!

Comment: it normally works for me and very thanks! I have a minor issue, when I use your defined `\mysymbol` for `\item` <- I belive that the code to change the item shape, but during compile, I use `pdfLatex` to compile, may I know what kind of compile you use?

Comment: Could you explain what's the function of `\vbox{}\vfill` and why the `\begingroup\endgroup` commands? Nice work, as usual.

Comment: @HowChen I use pdflatex too and got no problems. What kind of problem do you have?

Comment: @Ignasi Leftovers from the initial code I had. I will remove them since they are not really needed. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, `! Argument of \tikz@collect@coordinate@onpath has an extra }.` `! Paragraph ended before \tikz@collect@coordinate@onpath was complete.`, `! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`, I met it during compare if use the customized item

Comment: You can point also to http://science.thilucmic.fr/index.php?c=la&p=beamersheet&l=en --- it's a great resource for designing beamer templates.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I fix the pproblem after update the tex, I think my tex is too old, version 2013