# Powerpoint slides I'd like to replicate with beamer

Tags: beamer

I came across these powerpoint slides :

[image]

[image]

that I'd like to replicate with beamer, but I don't know how to do it.

I'd like to keep the orange color, as my presentation will be related to the Netherlands, but I would like to be able to work in mono or double column setting. Also, I'd like tu put my personal logos on it, at the same places where the logos are.

Is there a beamer theme/template allowing me to do this at a mininum cost ? (Almost never used beamer before ...)

Also, I would like text and maths to have the same caracters as in a latex document class article, is it possible in beamer ? (I remarked that by default it is not the case, which annoys me.) Is what the beamerarticle package is used for ?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/275114/how-to-create-beamer-template might be interesting if you want orange ...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you only have to change a few things from the default theme to get a similar look. If you would need all the details to be the same, then things get more complicated.

To give you something to start with, I changed the main colour to orange, included an image in the footline and changed the paper size.

If you find more elements you want to change http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf is helpful to find the names of the elements.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for this example

%\usefonttheme{serif}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=orange}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=1cm]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        bla bla bla
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        bla bla bla
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd add `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}` or `\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty` to the preamble. I've never seen anyone using them, they occupy space, do not exist in the original, and if one moves the mouse pointer out of the way to the corner one might  accidentally click on one of these icons.

Comment: @gernot good idea!