# beamer: treat footline as background?

Tags: beamer, header-footer, backgrounds

In the `beamer` class, the `footline` is inserted *after*, i. e. *on top of* the frame contents. This means that, if the frame content is very tall or, in any case, frame content is positioned in the same area as the footline, the footline will print over the frame content (i. e. the content will be hidden behind the opaque parts of the footline).

Is there any way to change this so that the footline will behave like background material?

Comment: use `\begin{frame}[plain]{...} ... \end{frame}` for a too large contents. Makes more sense than overwriting the footline

Comment: @Herbert That hides the headline as well, so not a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the footline layer, you could add the content of the footline to another layer which is behind the normal text. For example if your theme does not use the left sidebar, you could do:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}
  {%
  \tiny%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \rule{0pt}{.99\paperheight}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortinstitute}{}{~~(\insertshortinstitute)}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
  \vskip0pt%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\color{red}
x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline x\newline 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(see [How does beamer build the frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26299/how-does-beamer-build-the-frame/27302#27302) for more available layers)

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more? 1.) Why does the `\rule` have a height of exactly `.99\paperheight`? 2.) What is the purpose of `\leavevmode` at the beginning and `\vskip0pt` at the end? 3.) What about setting the height of the *actual* footline (`\setbeamertemplate{footline}`)? Does this have to be taken into account in some way?

Comment: @Socob The rule is just a quick hack to push the content down to the bottom of the page. The rest of the code is more or less copied from the original definition of the footline from the `infolines` theme (you did not specify any theme in your question, so I took one at random).

Comment: @Socob fixed the size problem, please see my edited code.

Comment: OK, so `.99\paperheight` was just the height that happened to work? Do you know why (e.g. why not the full `\paperheight`)? And can you say anything about 3.)? Your code sets an empty footline – shouldn’t it (nominally) have some invisible contents so that its height can affect the positioning of the frame contents?

Comment: @Socob The .99 worked, so I did not put more effort into this. Concerning 3. you could do `\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\rule{0pt}{0.32cm}}`, the effect is very small.

Comment: @samcarter Thank you very much for this answer. I am trying to implement this background solution on a footline that contains hyperlinks buttons. The MWE is posted here:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414777/hyperlinks-buttons-on-a-second-layer-with-respect-to-the-contents-of-the-frame I cannot find the way to merge this background solution with that particular footline.