# Hyperlinks buttons on a second layer with respect to the contents of the frame

Tags: beamer, header-footer, backgrounds, navigation, hyperlink

In the following frame, the footline with hyperlinks buttons overlap with two images:

[image]

Is there a way to declare in the preamble the hyperlink's footline to be in a second layer (background) respect to the content on each slide?

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%
%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\newcommand{\btVFill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}

\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{6}{5.2}\selectfont}

% Format of the title of every section:
\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}
  \begin{frame}{Outline}
       \tableofcontents[
         currentsection,
         sectionstyle=show/shaded,
         subsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded,
         subsubsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded/shaded
         ]
  \end{frame}
}

\newcounter{prevsec}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% Create footline: 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
        \setcounter{prevsec}{\thesection}
        \ifnum\theprevsec>1
            \addtocounter{prevsec}{-1}
        \fi

    \quad\hyperlinkpresentationstart{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to start}}%
    \quad\hyperlinksectionstart{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to section start}}%
%   \quad\hyperlink{moredetails}{\beamergotobutton{More details}}%
    \ifnum\thesection<\totvalue{section}%
        \quad\hyperlinksectionstartnext{\beamerskipbutton{Next section}}%
    \else%
        \quad \beamerskipbutton{Next section}%
    \fi%
    \quad\hyperlink{sec:\theprevsec}{\beamerskipbutton{Previous section}}%
    \vspace*{0.2cm}%
}


% Outline at the beginning of each subsection:
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

% Outline at the beginning of each subsubsection:
\AtBeginSubsubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

   \section{sec1}
    \begin{frame}%{ss}
    1st section/ page 1 out of 1
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    1st section/ page 2 out of 2
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[label=Detailed_Analysis]
        Detailed Analysis
    \end{frame}

    \section{sec2}

\def\Blablabla{

%Some text, some text some text
  \begin{enumerate}
\Fontvi
  \item Some text: Some info
  \item Some other text: Some other info
  \end{enumerate}
}
%
\begin{frame}%[plain]
%
\begin{table}
\centering
%\vspace{-1em}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
$A$ & $B$ & $C$ & $D$ and $E$  \\\hline
$1.1$ & $1.2$ & $1.3$ & $1.4$ & $1.5$
\end{tabular}
%\caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\end{table}
\vspace{-0.5em}
%
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}
\begin{minipage}[b][0.4\textheight][c]{.45\linewidth} \Blablabla \end{minipage}\\[1em]
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}\quad
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{frame}

    \section{sec3}
    \begin{frame}
    3rd section
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    More content on the 3rd section
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    Even More content on the 3rd section
    \end{frame}

    \end{document}
```

**Update**: The above code posted in the question has the functionality of displaying the outline every time we change section. When displaying that outline, it is also possible to jump to the selected section by clicking on it. For example, if we have finished section 1, the next slide is the outline highlighting the upcoming section 2, and also there is the possibility to click on the faded section 3 to jump to section 3:

[image]

By using @samcarter answer, now the outline still appears when beginning a new section, but the functionality of clicking on the name of the section to jump to that section is disabled, as shown in this *code 2*:

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\btVFill}{\vskip0pt plus 1filll}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}

\newcommand\Fontvi{\fontsize{6}{5.2}\selectfont}

\newcounter{prevsec}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}
  {%
  \tiny%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \rule{0pt}{.99\paperheight}%
        \setcounter{prevsec}{\thesection}
        \ifnum\theprevsec>1
            \addtocounter{prevsec}{-1}
        \fi

    \quad\hyperlinkpresentationstart{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to start}}%
    \quad\hyperlinksectionstart{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to section start}}%
%   \quad\hyperlink{moredetails}{\beamergotobutton{More details}}%
    \ifnum\thesection<\totvalue{section}%
        \quad\hyperlinksectionstartnext{\beamerskipbutton{Next section}}%
    \else%
        \quad \beamerskipbutton{Next section}%
    \fi%
    \quad\hyperlink{sec:\theprevsec}{\beamerskipbutton{Previous section}}%
    \vspace*{0.2cm}%
        }%
  \vskip0pt%
  }
\makeatother
%
% Outline at the beginning of every section:
\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}
  \begin{frame}{Outline}
       \tableofcontents[
         currentsection,
         sectionstyle=show/shaded,
         subsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded,
         subsubsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded/shaded
         ]
  \end{frame}
}

% Outline at the beginning of each subsection:
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

% Outline at the beginning of each subsubsection:
\AtBeginSubsubsection[]
{
    \begin{frame}{Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

   \section{sec1}
    \begin{frame}%{ss}
    1st section/ page 1 out of 1
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    1st section/ page 2 out of 2
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[label=Detailed_Analysis]
        Detailed Analysis
    \end{frame}

    \section{sec2}

\def\Blablabla{

%Some text, some text some text
  \begin{enumerate}
\Fontvi
  \item Some text: Some info
  \item Some other text: Some other info
  \end{enumerate}
}
%
\begin{frame}%[plain]
%
\begin{table}
\centering
%\vspace{-1em}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
$A$ & $B$ & $C$ & $D$ and $E$  \\\hline
$1.1$ & $1.2$ & $1.3$ & $1.4$ & $1.5$
\end{tabular}
%\caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\end{table}
\vspace{-0.5em}
%
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}
\begin{minipage}[b][0.4\textheight][c]{.45\linewidth} \Blablabla \end{minipage}\\[1em]
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}\quad
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{frame}

    \section{sec3}
    \begin{frame}
    3rd section
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    More content on the 3rd section
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    Even More content on the 3rd section
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

**Update 2:** In addition to this, the pdf generated with *code 2* seems to have wrong linking functionalities, e.g. if I open the pdf on page 2, if I locate the mouse somewhere about the right area, a `Go to page 1` info appears:

[image]

and if I do click, I am redirected to page 1.

This was uing `okular`. The same happens if I open the document with `evince`:

[image]

Comment: off-topic: but you don't need `\usepackage[]{hyperref}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The buttons seem to be still click-able, however you'll have to guess where they are.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{section}

\newcounter{prevsec}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% Format of the title of every section:
\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}
  \begin{frame}{Outline}
       \tableofcontents[
         currentsection,
         sectionstyle=show/shaded,
         subsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded,
         subsubsectionstyle=shaded/shaded/shaded/shaded
         ]
  \end{frame}
}


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t][.98\paperheight][b]{\textwidth}
      \tiny%
      \setcounter{prevsec}{\thesection}
      \ifnum\theprevsec>1
        \addtocounter{prevsec}{-1}
      \fi
        \quad\hyperlinkpresentationstart{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to start}}%
      \quad\hyperlinksectionstart{\beamerreturnbutton{Back to section start}}%
        \ifnum\thesection<\totvalue{section}%
        \quad\hyperlinksectionstartnext{\beamerskipbutton{Next section}}%
      \else%
        \quad \beamerskipbutton{Next section}%
      \fi%
      \quad\hyperlink{sec:\theprevsec}{\beamerskipbutton{Previous section}}%
    \end{minipage}   
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

  \section{sec1}
    \begin{frame}%{ss}
    1st section/ page 1 out of 1
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    1st section/ page 2 out of 2
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}[label=Detailed_Analysis]
        Detailed Analysis
    \end{frame}

    \section{sec2}
%
\begin{frame}%[plain]
%
\begin{table}
\centering
%\vspace{-1em}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
$A$ & $B$ & $C$ & $D$ and $E$  \\\hline
$1.1$ & $1.2$ & $1.3$ & $1.4$ & $1.5$
\end{tabular}
%\caption{\label{tab:widgets}An example table.}
\end{table}
\vspace{-0.5em}
%
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}
\begin{minipage}[b][0.4\textheight][c]{.45\linewidth} \end{minipage}\\[1em]
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}\quad
\includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{frame}

    \section{sec3}
    \begin{frame}
    3rd section
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    More content on the 3rd section
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
    Even More content on the 3rd section
    \end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, the functionality of clicking on the desired section in the outline has been disabled. Please see updated post for a detailed explanation

Comment: @DavidC. I just tested your code and the links in the outline work fine for me. Did you compile >= 2 times?

Comment: Yes, I have compiled 4 times. The problem still appears. (Just to avoid misunderstandings, I am referring to my second posted code, which implements your background solution, but within the  `\AtBeginSection` framework)

Comment: @DavidC. Yes, I used your second code (I had to add a documentclass to make it compilable) and clicking on this:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0SEI.png. How are you compiling? pdflatex or something else? Which tex distribution do you have? Which pdf viewer did you test? Can you boil it down to a minimal not working example?

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am compiling through terminal window on Linux Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS: `pdflatex main.tex` (x4 times) and visualizing with `okular main.pdf`.  By typing `pdflatex` in a new terminal there is this message: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)`.

Comment: @DavidC. To rule out possible causes of your problem: Could you test if the link in the following pdf work for you? https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmsydclxrp9utzx/document2.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the pdf, +1. I have downloaded and opened it with `okular` and the link to the sections still does not work. In addition, I have also noticed that there are also wrong linking functionalities. Please see update 2 for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Do you reproduce the wrong linking functionalities posted on the last update? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @DavidC. Sorry I kind of forgot about this question. It seems the linking problem depends on the pdf viewer - however I am not sure what's going wrong. I cannot reproduce the problem with the build in viewer of texstudio nor with adobe reader. However with mac preview I can reproduce it.

Comment: Ok, just to avoid misunderstandings, I am referring to the problem in the **Update 2**. Is it true that if you locate the mouse somewhere about the right area, a "Go to page 1" info appears / or if you do click in somewhere about the right area, you are redirected to page 1 ? Thanks again

Comment: @DavidC. I'll try to make a MNWE and report back.

Comment: @DavidC. Can you please test if my updated code works for you?

Comment: You replaced the `\hbox` scheme by a `minipage` scheme right? Is this strategy supposed to be more portable? Thanks again

Comment: @DavidC. Yes, the minipage is new. Not really sure, but I think the following was the problem: In the previous code I used a dirty hack to move the buttons to the end of the page by inserting an invisible rule at the start of the line. This effectively made the line as heigh as the total page. Some viewer seems to have a problem with this...

Comment: Thank you very much for all the effort. The `minipage` solution  does not give those problems